# In a pandas dataframe how do i add a field that is a running total with a group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas

mydata = [{'city': 'London', 'age': 75, 'fdg': 1.78},
          {'city': 'Paris', 'age': 22, 'fdg': 1.56},
          {'city': 'Paris', 'age': 32, 'fdg': 1.56},
          {'city': 'New York', 'age': 37, 'fdg': 1.56},
          {'city': 'London', 'age': 24, 'fdg': 1.56},
          {'city': 'London', 'age': 22, 'fdg': 1.56},
          {'city': 'New York', 'age': 60, 'fdg': 1.56},
          {'city': 'Paris', 'age': 22, 'fdg': 1.56},


          ]
df = pandas.DataFrame(mydata)

   age      city   fdg
0   75    London  1.78
1   22     Paris  1.56
2   32     Paris  1.56
3   37  New York  1.56
4   24    London  1.56
5   22    London  1.56
6   60  New York  1.56
7   22     Paris  1.56
```

I'd like to add a field to the end called age_total which will be a cumulative total of the age field.  The cumulative calculation would work over a group by of city - So row 1 for London would be 75, row 2 for Paris would be 22 and row 3 for Paris would be 54 - (22+32)

Comment: df['age_total']=df.groupby('city').cumsum()['age']  should do the trick

Comment: Perfect - thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
df['age_total']=df.groupby('city').cumsum()['age']
```

Comment: I'm just curious, what if he wanted an overall sum across the city grouping and not a running sum? What's the quickest way to approach that.

Comment: @RedVII That would be a usecase for `transform` df['overall_age_total'] = df.groupby('city)['age'].transform('sum')`